# Explicação RoundingMode de um DecimalFormat

Tags: java, tipagem, arredondamento

Alguém pode explicar o porquê do `format()` nos valores abaixo faz o *round* para ".6" nos dois primeiros valores e ".5" nos restantes?

#### Código:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.#");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println("0.55: " + df.format(0.55));
System.out.println("1.55: " + df.format(1.55));
System.out.println("2.55: " + df.format(2.55));
System.out.println("3.55: " + df.format(3.55));
System.out.println("4.55: " + df.format(4.55));
System.out.println("5.55: " + df.format(5.55));
```

#### Output:

```
0.55: 0.6
1.55: 1.6
2.55: 2.5
3.55: 3.5
4.55: 4.5
5.55: 5.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está mandando para a função um valor do tipo `double` que não possui exatidão. Para saber mais: [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Então tem valor que fica acima do que está vendo no código e tem valor que fica abaixo, e o arredondamento é feito em cima do valor real na memória, não da representação textual que está vendo no código, quando está abaixo ele arredonda para baixo, quando está igual ou acima arredonda para cima.

O ideal é não usar uma API que trabalhe com valor decimal mas recebe um tipo flutuante binário, tenho dúvidas se deveria existir isso.

Então o certo é mandar um valor já decimal:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.#");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("0.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.55)));
        System.out.println("1.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.55)));
        System.out.println("2.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.55)));
        System.out.println("3.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.55)));
        System.out.println("4.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.55)));
        System.out.println("5.55: " + df.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(5.55)));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fao3xq#stdout). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/vueqzqrcvc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/DoubleXDecimal.java).

Comment: Ótimo, obrigado!